# How to convert UNIX epoch seconds to Timestamp in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I could not find any function in snowflake docs that can do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand what you mean correctly it appears to be:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP( epoch_sec )
```

[This is the reference.](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html)  There's variations for time zone support too.

Comment: It works, Documentation nowhere states that to_timestamp functions can take epoch seconds too. There are no samples for it too. I have used to_timestamp_ntz( epoch seconds ).

Answer (score 3):

Actually the function `to_timestamp()` in order to determine the units to use (seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds), needs to receive a varchar instead of a bigint. So you just need to first cast the bigint to a varchar and you will be fine

```
select to_timestamp(31536000::varchar); --returns "1971-01-01" (correct)
select to_timestamp(31536000000::varchar); --returns "1971-01-01" (correct)
select to_timestamp(31536000000000::varchar); --returns "1971-01-01" (correct)
select to_timestamp(31536000000000000::varchar); --returns "1971-01-01" (correct)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for me

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a perfect solution for this issue. The [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html#usage-notes) do say that the `to_timestamp()` function supports epoch seconds, microseconds, and nanoseconds, however their own example using the number 31536000000000000 does not even work.

```
select to_timestamp(31536000000000000); -- returns "Invalid Date" (incorrect)
```

The number of digits your epoch number has will vary by its origin source. What I found helpful was using a tool like [epoch converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to input the full epoch number and determine what your date should be. Then try to get to that date in Snowflake using some manipulation. To get the real date for the example above:

```
select to_timestamp(left(31536000000000000, 11)); -- returns "1971-01-01" (correct)
```

You may notice that this is not set in stone. Adding or removing the number of digits you keep in your to_timestamp function will completely change the output, so you may need to add or remove numbers to get the date you are looking for. For example, the number 1418419324000000 should return date "2014-12-12"...

```
select to_timestamp(1418419324000000); -- returns "Invalid Date" (incorrect)
select to_timestamp(left(1418419324000000, 11)); -- returns "2419-06-24" (incorrect)
select to_timestamp(left(1418419324000000, 10)); -- returns "2014-12-12" (correct)
```

I had to play around with how many characters I input to get to where I needed to be. It's definitely a hack, but it's a simple solution to get there.